# How to put a lock on a file in a multi user environment?

Tags: c#-3.0

I have an executable which is hosted on a server and can be launched from several client work stations. The exe needs to read and write to a particular text file that is located on the same server(shared location). Since the exe can be launched from multiple work stations, I need to put a lock on the text file and do some processing and unlock the file so at any time, only one user will be able to access the file. Also, I need to display some message to the user when the file is locked by another user. Once the file is unlocked, it should be available for the other user to lock and do the processing.

Is there anybody who can provide some sample code snippet how to achieve this?
Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the file with Write access and with `FileShare.None`, which means it's not able to be written to by anyone else while the user has it open.

The `try..catch...` block will enable you to give them a message telling them the file is unavailable.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"YourfileLocationAndFileName");

try
{
    using(FileStream fileStream1 = file.Open(FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))  
    {
          //Use the filestream to do your readwrite here.
    }
}
catch(IOException ex)
{
    //pop up message box here to inform the user the file is currently in use
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I also need to make sure that the file can't be read when it is being accessed by another user. Can we do it using lock and unlock mechanisms in .Net? I can't simply show a message box to say the file is in use but rather I would need to provide a message to say the file is in use and provide an option to try again. When the user chooses the option to try again, it should keep checking if the file is unlocked by another user and continue processing when the file is available. Thank you very much for any ideas.

Comment: FileShare.None will make sure that it can't be read either. Yes there are more complicated ways of locking and unlocking (such as a mutex, etc.) but this is the simplest and (from what I can tell) best way for your situation. If you want to keep giving the user the option to keep trying, then you can put this in a loop and just keep trying, asking, trying, asking, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I would like to try FileShare.None. I would like to leave the question open for some time just in case if I need any more suggestions. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually I have two files to look if they are in use. If the first file is in use then it should keep trying, asking, etc. If the first file is available then open (lock) the second file. In this case, I can use another FileStream object within the first one. Correct?

Comment: You can nest within the using statement and the try catch block, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the file with `FileShare.None` using [this ctor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The mutex/semaphore technique for serializing access to a shared resource is slightly more involved but you can find many examples and explanations by doing a web search.  This technique will allow you to wait for the file to become available, control access to any granularity you need .

Basically when a writer wishes to lock the file, they must first acquire a mutex, which is an exclusive synchronization object.  If another writer has the mutex, the second requester can wait for it.  If you want to also allow read only access, you can add semaphores. Each reader acquires a semaphore to indicate they are reading the file.  Then when a writer acquires a mutex they must also wait for each reader to finish, as signaled by the semaphores.

It is not difficult to implement but more than I can show example code for.  As I say you can find many tutorials and examples on the web.